# Are there region specific Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-go

Are the Pokémon that appear in the Pokémon GO app region specific when it comes to elemental pokemon? I live in Arizona and got a Magikarp in an egg and I do not know where to find any more whatsoever and I am not looking forward to getting 400 points to make it evolve when I can't even find one.

Comment: "Region-specific" within Pokémon Go refers to the 4 Pokémon that can only be found in specific countries/continents (as you may now know). However, your mention of "elemental Pokémon" (more specifically Magikarp - a Water type Pokémon) suggests to me that you might be asking about locations or "Biomes" in which you can find specific Pokémon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few region specific pokemon out in the wild, but you can still get them from eggs.

[image]

Magikarp is not region specific so your best bet is going near a large body of water. There are more of these than any other near a river near me.

Comment: Oh ok, I have heard of magikarp being very annoying and abundant for some people and that is probably why it evolves at 400, thank you!

Comment: @KyleDoobs that, and to represent the original grind you needed in the original games. But the Gyrados is worth it :)

Comment: Darn right Gyarados is always worth it! I mean it is one of the strongest and not to mention BA pokemon in the first gen! I mean why else would they make you level up a fish that flops around and does no damage to lvl 20? lol in this case 400...